# Correct way to save modifications in childs of Aggregate root

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories, ef-core-2.1

I have this aggregateRoot :

```
 public class Room : Entity
{
    public Room()
    {
        RoomRates = new HashSet<RoomRate>();
    }


    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<RoomRate> RoomRates { get; }

    public int HotelId { get; set; }

    public void AddRoomRate(DateRange period, Money price)
    {

       RecalculateRates(period);

       RoomRates.Add(new RoomRate{Period = period, Price = price, RoomId = Id});

    }
```

Child:

```
public class RoomRate : Entity
{

    public DateRange Period { get; set; }

    public Money Price { get; set; }

    public int RoomId { get; set; }

    public void SetStart(DateTime start) {
        Period = new DateRange(start, Period.End);

    }

    public void SetEnd(DateTime end)
    {
        Period = new DateRange(Period.Start, end);

    }


}
```

The RecalculateRates method can add or modify the childs:

```
foreach (var rateToReArrange in ratesToReArrange)
        {
            var periodToReArrange = rateToReArrange.Period;

            if (periodToReArrange.Contains(ratePeriod))
            {
                RoomRates.Add(new RoomRate
                {
                    Period = new DateRange(periodToReArrange.Start, dayBeforePeriodStarts),
                    Price = rateToReArrange.Price, RoomId = rateToReArrange.RoomId
                });



                rateToReArrange.SetStart(dayAfterPeriodEnds); 

                return;


            }

            if (rateToReArrange.Period.StartsInRange(ratePeriod))
            {
                rateToReArrange.SetStart(dayAfterPeriodEnds); 

                return;
            }

            if (rateToReArrange.Period.EndsInRange(ratePeriod))
            {
                rateToReArrange.SetEnd(dayBeforePeriodStarts);

                return;
            }
        }
```

After add child an recalculate i wan tto save the root:

```
room.AddRoomRate(new DateRange(request.Start,request.End), new Money(request.Amount, request.Currency.ToString()));

        _context.Rooms.Update(room);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

I cannot update the entity because there is new childs. How  should i save modification in the root?

I am using CQRS and i am trying to add a new rate in a command. Should i create a repository?

Comment: _I cannot update the entity because there is new childs_ Why? Aren't you tracking the entity?

Answer (score 1):

There should be a repository for each aggregate, so you should have a room repository.

But the repository pattern is an abstraction of a collection of objects, you don't have any update method, just add, remove and get.

To update an object you just get it from the repository and modify it.

It's the persistence mechanism implementing the repository who will take care of tracking the changes made to the object (including the childs of the root) wrapping them in a transaction and doing the commit to save them to the db.

See http://codebetter.com/iancooper/2011/04/12/repository-saveupdate-is-a-smell/

Hope it helps.